# Issue in sas data set

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

Right now I am having a column in sas data set.This dataset has been created in sas enterprie guide EG

```
S.NO.  COUNT
1       5
2       6
3       7
4       2
5       10
```

Now the dataset that I desire.

```
S.NO.  COUNT   MASKED
1       5      XXXXX
2       6      XXXXXX
3       7      XXXXXXX
4       2      XX
5       10     XXXXXXXXXX
```

Basically the number present in the count,I want that many 'x' in the 'MASKED' column.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS proc SQL, try the `repeat()` function:

```
select t.*, repeat('X', count)
from t;
```

Comment: How will I use this if i am using data and set command in sas.

Comment: `masked = repeat('X', count-1);`